# Opposite of Job Assignment Problem.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

We have a bipartite graph with two sets $X,Y$.
Size of $X$ = 100000
Size of $Y$ = 25
We have edges from members in $X$ to $Y$.
We need to form set $Z$ by picking minimum number of elements from $Y$ so that each element of $X$ points to atleast one member in $Z$.

Comment: There are several possible algorithms whose efficiency may depend on the particular pattern of edges.  One approach might be to start with all of $Y$ and then try to remove individual elements until the condition is not met

Comment: This is the set cover problem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem, think of $Y$ as the sets, $X$ as the elements and edges $xy$ mean $x \in Y$).  This is NP-hard.  But since $Y$ is not too big, brute-forcing every possible subset of $Y$ might be OK (there are about 35 million subsets, which is not too bad for a computer).

Comment: @ManuelLafond But for every subset, I will have to check all  $10^5$ elements. That adds up quite a lot.